# Multiple iframes on the one page with iFrame Resizer

Tags: iframe-resizer

The docs for iFrame Resizer say:

> When the resizer does not work using multiple IFrames on one page, make sure that each frame has an unique id or no ids at all.

I have chosen to give no ids to the iframes. My code is shown below. It works but I wanted to confirm that I am doing everything correctly. Specifically, I am calling iFrameResize() only once and with no arguments - is that ok?

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/frame1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com/frame2" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.15/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script>iFrameResize()</script>
```

**Note**: @david_bradshaw, I decided not to use ids, because in that case it was not clear how to call `iFrameResize()` - do we need to call it once for each iFrame? Please clarify. TIA

Comment: Yes that is correct, Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Also as the answer below states make sure you have the other JS file in both iFrames.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @DavidBradshaw. To answer your questions, I am not seeing any errors in the console and I have included `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js` in the site serving the iframe content. I can even see clean logs when I turn them on. I am noticing though that both the iframes are automatically getting ids: `iFrameResizer0` & `iFrameResizer1` - which is good. So the only remaining question is whether the single call to `iFrameResize()` without any arguments is good enough or do I need two calls: `iFrameResize({}, "#iFrameResizer0")` & `iFrameResize({}, "#iFrameResizer1")`

Comment: Hmmm, I tried to call `iFrameResize()` twice, once with each id and I get an additional bonus that logs tell me which iframe the messages are from. So I am guess two instances are created with better information.

Comment: You only need to make the call once

Comment: @DavidBradshaw, as you suggest, I will make the iFrameResize() call only once. Just confirming - in that case I will not be passing any iframe ids into the call, correct? The exact call will look like this: `iFrameResize()`

Comment: Yep that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest putting ID's in.

Not sure if this will help.

> - Requires: iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js to be loaded into the target frame.

**Reference:** [cloudflare.com](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.15/iframeResizer.min.js) (21-Jan-2018)

Example

```
<style>iframe{width: 1px;min-width: 100%;}</style>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://anotherdomain.com/iframe.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<script>iFrameResize({log:true}, '#myIframe')</script>
```

**Reference:** [davidjbradshaw](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) (21-Jan-2018)

**NOTE:** *ID Being used to sent to resizer method*.